# using multiple listviews with simple adapter and hashmap

Tags: android, listview, hashmap, simpleadapter

hey everyone i hope you can help and thanks for taking the time too look

im trying to use multilpe listviews in the one activity with a simple adapter and a hashmap

here is some of my code....

```
final ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> listGeneral = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
```

before the onCreate then is in the onCreate

```
setContentView(R.layout.custom_list_view);

        SimpleAdapter adapter1 = new SimpleAdapter(
                this,
                listGeneral,
                R.layout.custom_row_view,
                new String[] {"catGeneral","score1"},
                new int[] {R.id.text1,R.id.text2}
        );

setList1();
 setListAdapter(adapter1);
```

setList1

```
public void setList1(){

        HashMap<String,String> temp = new HashMap<String,String>();
        temp.put("catGeneral","General Knowledge Lv1");
        temp.put("score1", level3);
        listGeneral.add(temp);

        HashMap<String,String> temp1 = new HashMap<String,String>();
        temp1.put("catGeneral","General Knowledge Lv2");
        temp1.put("score1", level4);
        listGeneral.add(temp1);

        HashMap<String,String> temp2 = new HashMap<String,String>();
        temp2.put("catGeneral","General Knowledge Lv3");
        temp2.put("score1", level2);
        listGeneral.add(temp2);
}
```

and itemListener

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);


        if (position == 0){
        Toast.makeText(this, "one", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if (position == 1){
            Toast.makeText(this, "two", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        else if (position == 2){
            Toast.makeText(this, "three", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        else if (position == 3){
            Toast.makeText(this, "four", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        else if (position == 4){
            Toast.makeText(this, "five", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
       }
```

and xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#000fff"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false">
    </ListView>

    <TextView android:id="@id/android:empty"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:background="#FFff00"
        android:text="No data"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

all of this works for one listview. But when i add a second list

```
final ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> listPopCulture = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
SimpleAdapter adapter2 = new SimpleAdapter(
                this,
                listPopCulture,
                R.layout.custom_row_view,
                new String[] {"catPopCulture","score2"},
                new int[] {R.id.text1,R.id.text2}
        );


setList2();
setListAdapter(adapter2);

public void setList2(){

        HashMap<String,String> temp = new HashMap<String,String>();
        temp.put("catPopCulture","The 60's");
        temp.put("score2", level3);
        listPopCulture.add(temp);

        HashMap<String,String> temp1 = new HashMap<String,String>();
        temp1.put("catPopCulture","The 70's");
        temp1.put("score2", level4);
        listPopCulture.add(temp1);

        HashMap<String,String> temp2 = new HashMap<String,String>();
        temp2.put("catPopCulture","The 80's");
        temp2.put("score2", level2);
        listPopCulture.add(temp2);
}
```

im not sure how to do the second itemListener for the second list, aswell as how to call the second list, as i thought the first list is called by `android:id="@id/android:list"`
everything i have tried hasnt worked....

is it because simple adapter isnt able to be set on more then one list per activity because of its id ? and how do i declare the second or more listviews in the one xml file. In the end i want a layout with a scrollview that holds a textview then listview, then another textview and another listview....any help would be awsome

here is edited answer almost their. works but i need onItemListener for list2 and list3

```
setContentView(R.layout.custom_list_view);

        ListView list2 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list2);
        ListView list3 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list3);



        SimpleAdapter adapter1 = new SimpleAdapter(
                this,
                listGeneral,
                R.layout.custom_row_view,
                new String[] {"catGeneral","score1"},
                new int[] {R.id.text1,R.id.text2}
        );
        //list1.setAdapter(adapter1);


        SimpleAdapter adapter2 = new SimpleAdapter(
                this,
                listPopCulture,
                R.layout.custom_row_view,
                new String[] {"catPopCulture","score2"},
                new int[] {R.id.text1,R.id.text2}
        );

        SimpleAdapter adapter3 = new SimpleAdapter(
                this,
                listKids,
                R.layout.custom_row_view,
                new String[] {"catKids","score3"},
                new int[] {R.id.text1,R.id.text2}
        );

        setList1();
        setList2();
        setList3();

                setListAdapter(adapter1);
        list2.setAdapter(adapter2);
        list3.setAdapter(adapter3);

        //end oncreate  
    }

    public void setList1(){

        HashMap<String,String> temp = new HashMap<String,String>();
        temp.put("catGeneral","General Knowledge Lv1");
        temp.put("score1", level3);
        listGeneral.add(temp);

        HashMap<String,String> temp1 = new HashMap<String,String>();
        temp1.put("catGeneral","General Knowledge Lv2");
        temp1.put("score1", level4);
        listGeneral.add(temp1);

        HashMap<String,String> temp2 = new HashMap<String,String>();
        temp2.put("catGeneral","General Knowledge Lv3");
        temp2.put("score1", level2);
        listGeneral.add(temp2);

        HashMap<String,String> temp3 = new HashMap<String,String>();
        temp3.put("catGeneral","General Knowledge Lv4");
        temp3.put("score1", level3);
        listGeneral.add(temp3);

        HashMap<String,String> temp4 = new HashMap<String,String>();
        temp4.put("catGeneral", "General Knowledge Lv5");
        temp4.put("score1", level1);
        listGeneral.add(temp4);

        HashMap<String,String> temp5 = new HashMap<String,String>();
        temp5.put("catGeneral", "General Knowledge Lv6");
        temp5.put("score1", level1);
        listGeneral.add(temp5);
    }
```

my working listener for list 1

```
 //list 1 listener
        protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
            super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
            if (position == 0){
            Toast.makeText(this, "one", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else if (position == 1){
                Toast.makeText(this, "two", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            else if (position == 2){
                Toast.makeText(this, "three", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            else if (position == 3){
                Toast.makeText(this, "four", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            else if (position == 4){
                Toast.makeText(this, "five", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
           }
```

ive tried this for list2 onItemClick

```
list2.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id) {
                if (position == 0){
                    Toast.makeText(this, "one", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else if (position == 1){
                        Toast.makeText(this, "two", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    else if (position == 2){
                        Toast.makeText(this, "three", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    else if (position == 3){
                        Toast.makeText(this, "four", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    else if (position == 4){
                        Toast.makeText(this, "five", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
            }
        });
```

any ideas on the list2 and list3 onItemClick?

Answer (score 1):

Put two list in your xml :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/list1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#000fff"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false">
</ListView>

<ListView android:id="@+id/list2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#000fff"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false">
</ListView>

<TextView android:id="@id/android:empty"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:background="#FFff00"
    android:text="No data"
/>
```

Now in your main activity, create your adapter like you do above.
Get the list references like this :-

```
ListView list1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list1);
ListView list2 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list2);
list1.setAdapter(adapter);
list2.setAdapter(secondadapter);
```

Comment: when i left android:id="@id/android:list" for the first listview your code worked

Comment: but how do i implament the second onItemListener ill repost an edit

Comment: You can write hundreds itemclick listener for different listview's just like you have written above for list2